# Verilog module to read/write a register

Tags: verilog, memory

I would like to create a module that can change the value of a register passed to it (+/- 1) using an inout port. I wrote this:

```
module tune(
    input clk,
    input read,
    input [15:0] x,
    inout [15:0] y,
    input plus,
    input minus
);

reg [15:0] a;
reg [15:0] b;

assign y = read ? a:'bz;

always@(posedge clk) begin
    b<=y;
    a<=x;
    if (plus) b<=b+1;
end

endmodule
```

When *read* is HIGH, I expect *y* to be initialized to the value of *x*. 
When *read* is LOW, I expect to output the value of *b* (which can be decremented or incremented by using *minus* or *plus*). 
Currently however, *plus* does not do anything, and *read* toggles *y* between 0xFFFF and 2 (when I pass 2'd42 to x).

I admit I do not have a good grasp of non-blocking assignments. What should I change to make my code work, or is there a better way to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: Are you writing this for synthesis, or only for simulation?

Comment: for synthesis on a Nexys 3

Comment: Are you trying to make a counter with a load function and tristate-buffered outputs?

Answer (score 1):

> When read is HIGH, I expect y to be initialized to the value of x.

The only thing your code actually does when `read` is high is to make `y` output the value from `a`. As soon as `read` goes low again `y` goes back to being an input (because you assign it the value `z`).

> When read is LOW, I expect to output the value of b (which can be decremented or incremented by using minus or plus).

Since `b` is not an output, and you never use `b` to set any other wire or register, it's not clear how you expect that to happen.

> Currently however, plus does not do anything

Are you sure? In your code, if `plus` is high at a rising edge of `clk`, then `b` will get the value `y+1`.

> and read toggles y between 0xFFFF and 2

Are you sure the value is 0xFFFF and not 0xXXXX? Because when `read` is low, this code is not assigning any value at all to `y`. It sounds like your testbench is applying a pull-up or a weak high value to the bits of `y`.

Comment: I assume that b<=y makes y connected to b, as well as 'bz.

Comment: No. That only makes b get the value from y. It doesn't make y get the value from b.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the end

```
module tune #(parameter INIT=0, DELAY=19, BITS=16)(
    input clk,
    output reg [BITS-1:0] y = INIT,
    input enb,
    input add,
    input sub
);

reg [DELAY:0] count = 0;

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (add^sub && count==0 && enb) y = add ? y+1:y-1;
    count <= count + 1;
end

endmodule
```